# How to do `Parentobject1` into `childobject2`, `childobject3` add or draw in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created two objects `doubleSquare` and `doubleSquare1`. I expected output `Double Line Square Object`. I have tried two type of format but not getting the expected output. Please, provide me the solution. I have seen lot of example while doing website analysis. What did I do wrong in the code?

`Type 1` (In the below code `doubleSquare` closepath start with another object draw.How to split? )

```
function doubleSquareDemoDraw(startX, startY, endX, endY, color){
var widthLength = Math.round(Math.abs(endX - startX));
         var heightLength = Math.round(Math.abs(endY - startY));
         console.log(widthLength+'::'+heightLength);

         var combined = new THREE.Geometry(); 
         var doubleSquare = new THREE.Geometry();
          doubleSquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0));
          doubleSquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(endX, startY, 0));
          doubleSquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(endX, endY, 0));
          doubleSquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(startX, endY, 0));
          doubleSquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0));
          doubleSquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0)); //closepath



        var doubleSquare1 = new THREE.Geometry();
        doubleSquare1.vertices.push(
            new THREE.Vector3(startX + 4, startY- 4 , 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(endX -4, startY- 4, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(endX - 4, endY +4, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(startX + 4, endY + 4, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(startX + 4, startY -4 , 0)
        );

        THREE.GeometryUtils.merge( combined, doubleSquare );
        THREE.GeometryUtils.merge( combined, doubleSquare1 );

        var display = new THREE.Line(combined, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: color }));

        return display;
}
```

Type 2 (In the below code only single object is visible instead of Two)

```
function doubleSquareDraw(startX, startY, endX, endY, color){

       var combined = new THREE.Geometry(); 
       var square1 = new THREE.Shape();
       square1.moveTo(startX, startY, 0);
       square1.lineTo(endX, startY, 0);
       square1.lineTo(endX, endY, 0);
       square1.lineTo(startX, endY, 0);
       square1.lineTo(startX, startY, 0);

       var square2 = new THREE.Path();
       square2.moveTo(startX + 4 , startY  - 4  , 0);
       square2.lineTo(endX - 4  , startY - 4  , 0);
       square2.lineTo(endX - 4 , endY + 4  , 0);
       square2.lineTo(startX + 4  , endY + 4  , 0);
       square2.lineTo(startX + 4  , startY  - 4  , 0);
       square1.holes.push( square2);

       var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(square.getPoints());  
      var square = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: color
        })); 
        return display;
    }
```

Comment: Tried editing your code but still not able to figure our what exactly you want.

Comment: I expect result one object into another object. How to add? and visible single object example `face diagram` circle , Two eyes, and mouth. How to add circle object into another object add? Here I expected double line square object

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the source code of this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shapes#webgl_geometry_shapes) more attentively, then you will see, that the lines for shapes and for their holes are drawn separately.

For example, that shape `arcShape`:

1. We set the shape and its hole [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/608fb12d7cdb7d9bdce193d9c9e63fa082b8de81/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html#L294L303)
2. We pass that shape into [`addShape( arcShape, extrudeSettings, 0x804000,  150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/608fb12d7cdb7d9bdce193d9c9e63fa082b8de81/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html#L358)
3. Inside `addShape` we call `addLineShape( shape, color, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz, s );`, which draws the outer contour line of the shape;
4. And to draw the hole inside the cirle, we call `addLineShape()`, passing the path of that hole in the first parameter. [Here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/608fb12d7cdb7d9bdce193d9c9e63fa082b8de81/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html#L361).

From what I see in your code, you think, if you set a shape and its holes and then create a buffer geometry with `new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(shape.getPoints())`, then you get a contour line of the shape and contour lines of its holes. You're wrong, as the things work different.